# get the date difference in milliseconds in oracle

Tags: datetime, oracle11g

I need to get he difference between end date and start date in milliseconds inside a view in oracle 11g. I can get these two dates from the database in 07-JUN-12 04.32.21.092000000 AM format. All I need is to find the diff of these kind of dates in milliseconds

Comment: What are the data types of these columns?  You say `date` repeatedly but `date` columns do not contain milliseconds.  Are these really `timestamp` columns?  If so, are they `timestamp`, `timestamp with time zone`, or `timestamp with local time zone` columns?

Comment: Timestamp is the type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT ((extract(DAY FROM time2-time1)*24*60*60)+ 
(extract(HOUR FROM time2-time1)*60*60)+
(extract(MINUTE FROM time2-time1)*60)+
extract(SECOND FROM time2-time1)) *1000
as millisecs FROM dual;
```

can be done using above approach

Answer (score 1):

```
select (DATE1 - DATE2) as days,
(DATE1 - DATE2) * 24 as hours,
(DATE1 - DATE2) * 24 * 60 as minutes,
(DATE1 - DATE2) * 24 * 60 * 60 as seconds,
(DATE1 - DATE2) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 as milliseconds
 from dual
```

EDIT - I assumed DateTime type.  However, Justin Cave's question is very relevant.  A Timestamp is not the same as a DateTime, so my answer won't work if you are dealing with Timestamps.

In that case, see this http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_timestamp_math_elapsed_times.htm.